# body shrinks more than 100% on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

When I resize the browser, it works fine, but on mobile and when I inspect on mobile size the body starts to shrink. The more I reduce, the more the body shrinks.

Any Ideas?

This is my website: http://www.mydeepwellbeing.com/

[image: normal at 425]

[image: 320 it is already weird]

[image: the lower I go the wierder it looks]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div.full-background{
   background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Might be a little help ^_^

Comment: just to be safe. I don't have a div.full-background, so should I create one as a wrapper for the content?

Comment: just combine code from me, ex. from -webkit untill background-size not everything ;)

Comment: It didn't actually work. It ended up being the size of the h3 tag. The h3 titles were going over the border.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being the h3 tag was too large on mobile, so the title was bigger than the body.
As soon as I lowered the font-size for h3 on mobile, it worked perfectly.